# How to add a tag above a category post that displays the category name in Wordpress

Tags: categories

I am wondering how I can display the category name on top of each article on this page. For example, each of the articles on this page are from multiple categories. Preferably, the category name would appear above the article title and below the photo.

I tried some of the settings in the Scene theme to no avail. I am guessing I'll have to jump in the PHP and code in the action to display the category name.

Here is the URL for the website: http://cultmontreal.com/music-nightlife/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`single_cat_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) that should do what you want.

> ### Description
>
> Displays or returns the page title if a category or tag archive is queried. Therefore, the
>   function can be used only outside [the loop](/The_Loop).